# Hadoop: ERROR BlockSender.sendChunks() exception

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, cluster-computing

I have a cluster to use Hadoop (one master that works as namenode and datanode, and two slaves). I saw in the log files these messages of error:

hadoop-hduser-datanode-master.log file:

```
2017-05-15 13:02:55,303 ERROR org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode: BlockSender.sendChunks() exception: 
java.io.IOException: Tubería rota
at sun.nio.ch.FileChannelImpl.transferTo0(Native Method)
at sun.nio.ch.FileChannelImpl.transferToDirectlyInternal(FileChannelImpl.java:428)
at sun.nio.ch.FileChannelImpl.transferToDirectly(FileChannelImpl.java:493)
at sun.nio.ch.FileChannelImpl.transferTo(FileChannelImpl.java:608)
at org.apache.hadoop.net.SocketOutputStream.transferToFully(SocketOutputStream.java:223)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.BlockSender.sendPacket(BlockSender.java:570)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.BlockSender.sendBlock(BlockSender.java:739)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataXceiver.readBlock(DataXceiver.java:527)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocol.datatransfer.Receiver.opReadBlock(Receiver.java:116)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocol.datatransfer.Receiver.processOp(Receiver.java:71)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataXceiver.run(DataXceiver.java:239)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

That happened only in the master node, after a while of inactivity. Fifteen minutes before, I ran a wordcount example successfully.

The OS in each node is Ubuntu 16.04. The cluster was created using VirtualBox.

Could you help me, please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I followed this link: 
https://hortonworks.com/blog/how-to-plan-and-configure-yarn-in-hdp-2-0/ 
to configure some parameters about the memory and my problem was resolved!

Note: in some posts I read that this error could be for lack of disk space (non in my case) and in other the reason was the SO's version (they recommended downgrade Ubuntu 16.04 to 14.04).